# How to join multiple Python scripts together into one script?

Tags: python

Is it possible to easily link each one to the scripts to 'A Complete Formula', as I have to do it multiple times and adding daily?

I have been compiling many of my own python scripts to calculate various math equations. I have over 15 scripts that I want to put together.

I am one of those people who will prefer to have something I can just press and it does the task automatically other than doing in manually - even if it takes twice as long at the start.

I have been just copying and pasting into the 'main' script that I can turn into an .exe but I have found that I have been changing, finding errors or making it better on the original file.

```
from math import *
from os import system, name
import math

def clear(): 

    if name == 'nt': 
        _ = system('cls')

while True:
    print("Area of Circle (1)\nArea of a Parallelogram (2)\nArea of a Quadrants and Semicirlces (3)\nArea of a Rectangle (4)\nArea of a Rhombus (5)\nArea of a Trapezium (6)\nArea of a Triangle (7)\nCircumfrence of a Circle (8)\nCircumfrence of a Quadrant or Semicircle (9)\nVolume of a Cylinder (10)\nVolume of a Parallelogram Prism (11)\nVolume of a Rectangular Prism (12)\nVolume of a Rhomus Prism (13)\nVolume of a Sphere (14)\nVolume of a Trapezium Prism (15)\nVolume of a Triangle Prism (16)")
    print()
    choice = input("Choose Formular: ")

    if choice == "1":
        print("Area of a Circle")
        num = float(input("Radius of Circle: "))
        rud = int(input("Place of rounding: "))
        ans = math.pi * num ** int("2")
        print(round(ans, rud))
        input("Press Enter to continue...")
        clear()
```

Comment: does the UI for user input exists in this script only, or is it the same in the others too.

Comment: You can use `importlib.import_module()` to `import` (and thereby execute) a  script by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the scripts.

Let's say you have the files with the individual formulas as `formula1.py`, `formula2.py`, etc with one function in it, `solve()` that does all the work. Asking for input, calculating, then giving the output. You can then do it like this.

```
import formula1, formula2, formula3
while True:
    ...
    if choice == '1': formula1.solve()
    elif choice == '2': formula2.solve()
    elif choice == '3': formula3.solve()
    else: print('Wrong Choice')
```

If you want your individual files to work as well then you can write them like this:

```
def solve():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    solve()
```

Do take care that without the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause, importing the file will also run it.

Comment: Would it work if I did `choice == '1': formula1.print(round(ans, rud))`

Comment: @NicolasHanna `formula1` is the name of the file. So `formula1.print()` will call the print function in the file `formula1`. By the way, if you have already calculated the answer, then there is no point in importing `formula1`